# setting date time picker in android

Tags: android

I am using a date picker and time picker in my application. I want to set both in same dialog box. or at the same time i want to set date and time.Is this possible?how so?pls give me a example.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

use following function

```
private void showDateTimeDialog() {
    // Create the dialog
    final Dialog mDateTimeDialog = new Dialog(this);
    // Inflate the root layout
    final RelativeLayout mDateTimeDialogView = (RelativeLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.date_time_dialog, null);
    // Grab widget instance
    final DateTimePicker mDateTimePicker = (DateTimePicker) mDateTimeDialogView.findViewById(R.id.DateTimePicker);
    // Check is system is set to use 24h time (this doesn't seem to work as expected though)
    final String timeS = android.provider.Settings.System.getString(getContentResolver(), android.provider.Settings.System.TIME_12_24);
    final boolean is24h = !(timeS == null || timeS.equals("12"));

    // Update demo TextViews when the "OK" button is clicked 
    ((Button) mDateTimeDialogView.findViewById(R.id.SetDateTime)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            /*((TextView) findViewById(R.id.Date)).setText(mDateTimePicker.get(Calendar.YEAR) + "/" + (mDateTimePicker.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1) + "/"
                    + mDateTimePicker.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
            if (mDateTimePicker.is24HourView()) {
                ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.Time)).setText(mDateTimePicker.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + ":" + mDateTimePicker.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
            } else {
                ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.Time)).setText(mDateTimePicker.get(Calendar.HOUR) + ":" + mDateTimePicker.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + " "
                        + (mDateTimePicker.get(Calendar.AM_PM) == Calendar.AM ? "AM" : "PM"));
            }*/

            String date =  (mDateTimePicker.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1) + "/" + mDateTimePicker.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)  + "/"
                    +mDateTimePicker.get(Calendar.YEAR)+"  "+mDateTimePicker.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + ":" + mDateTimePicker.get(Calendar.MINUTE)+" "+(mDateTimePicker.get(Calendar.AM_PM) == Calendar.AM ? "AM" : "PM");
            edt_admin_due_date.setText(date);
            mDateTimeDialog.dismiss();
        }//MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm
    });

    // Cancel the dialog when the "Cancel" button is clicked
    ((Button) mDateTimeDialogView.findViewById(R.id.CancelDialog)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mDateTimeDialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    // Reset Date and Time pickers when the "Reset" button is clicked
    ((Button) mDateTimeDialogView.findViewById(R.id.ResetDateTime)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mDateTimePicker.reset();
        }
    });

    // Setup TimePicker
    mDateTimePicker.setIs24HourView(is24h);
    // No title on the dialog window
    mDateTimeDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    // Set the dialog content view
    mDateTimeDialog.setContentView(mDateTimeDialogView);
    // Display the dialog
    mDateTimeDialog.show();
}
```

and datetimepicker file is as follow.

```
public class DateTimePicker extends RelativeLayout implements View.OnClickListener, OnDateChangedListener, OnTimeChangedListener {

// DatePicker reference
private DatePicker      datePicker;
// TimePicker reference
private TimePicker      timePicker;
// ViewSwitcher reference
private ViewSwitcher    viewSwitcher;
// Calendar reference
private Calendar        mCalendar;

// Constructor start
public DateTimePicker(Context context) {
    this(context, null);
}

public DateTimePicker(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, 0);
}

public DateTimePicker(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);

    // Get LayoutInflater instance
    final LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    // Inflate myself
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.datetimepicker, this, true);

    // Inflate the date and time picker views
    final LinearLayout datePickerView = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.datepicker, null);
    final LinearLayout timePickerView = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.timepicker, null);

    // Grab a Calendar instance
    mCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    // Grab the ViewSwitcher so we can attach our picker views to it
    viewSwitcher = (ViewSwitcher) this.findViewById(R.id.DateTimePickerVS);

    // Init date picker
    datePicker = (DatePicker) datePickerView.findViewById(R.id.DatePicker);
    datePicker.init(mCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), mCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), mCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), this);

    // Init time picker
    timePicker = (TimePicker) timePickerView.findViewById(R.id.TimePicker);
    timePicker.setOnTimeChangedListener(this);

    // Handle button clicks
    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.SwitchToTime)).setOnClickListener(this); // shows the time picker
    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.SwitchToDate)).setOnClickListener(this); // shows the date picker

    // Populate ViewSwitcher
    viewSwitcher.addView(datePickerView, 0);
    viewSwitcher.addView(timePickerView, 1);
}
// Constructor end

// Called every time the user changes DatePicker values
public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
    // Update the internal Calendar instance
    mCalendar.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth, mCalendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), mCalendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
}

// Called every time the user changes TimePicker values
public void onTimeChanged(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
    // Update the internal Calendar instance
    mCalendar.set(mCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), mCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), mCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), hourOfDay, minute);
}

// Handle button clicks
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.SwitchToDate:
            v.setEnabled(false);
            findViewById(R.id.SwitchToTime).setEnabled(true);
            viewSwitcher.showPrevious();
            break;

        case R.id.SwitchToTime:
            v.setEnabled(false);
            findViewById(R.id.SwitchToDate).setEnabled(true);
            viewSwitcher.showNext();
            break;
    }
}

// Convenience wrapper for internal Calendar instance
public int get(final int field) {
    return mCalendar.get(field);
}

// Reset DatePicker, TimePicker and internal Calendar instance
public void reset() {
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    updateDate(c.get(Calendar.YEAR), c.get(Calendar.MONTH), c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    updateTime(c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),c.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
}

// Convenience wrapper for internal Calendar instance
public long getDateTimeMillis() {
    return mCalendar.getTimeInMillis();
}

// Convenience wrapper for internal TimePicker instance
public void setIs24HourView(boolean is24HourView) {
    timePicker.setIs24HourView(is24HourView);
}

// Convenience wrapper for internal TimePicker instance
public boolean is24HourView() {
    return timePicker.is24HourView();
}

// Convenience wrapper for internal DatePicker instance
public void updateDate(int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
    datePicker.updateDate(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
}

// Convenience wrapper for internal TimePicker instance
public void updateTime(int currentHour, int currentMinute) {
    timePicker.setCurrentHour(currentHour);
    timePicker.setCurrentMinute(currentMinute);
}
```

}

this will work fine in my code

Comment: Thanks for the workaround to using `Settings.System.TIME_12_24` ...my logic used to work, where did that bug come from?!

Answer (score 0):

Following code will help you to get both,

date_time_picker.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

 <ScrollView android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <DatePicker android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/datePicker"></DatePicker>
    <TimePicker android:id="@+id/timePicker"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TimePicker>
    <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow1" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:gravity="center">

        <Button android:id="@+id/btnSetDateTime"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Set"
            android:layout_width="120dp"></Button>

    </TableRow>
</LinearLayout>
```

use the following java code:

```
ScrollView DTPicker = (ScrollView) View.inflate(context,
                    R.layout.date_time_picker, null);

        Button  btnSet = (Button) DTPicker.findViewById(R.id.btnSetDateTime);
            DatePicker dp = (DatePicker) DTPicker.findViewById(R.id.datePicker);
             TimePicker tp = (TimePicker) DTPicker.findViewById(R.id.timePicker);

            btnSet.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String strDateTime = dp.getYear() + "-"
                            + (dp.getMonth() + 1) + "-"
                            + dp.getDayOfMonth() + " "
                            + tp.getCurrentHour() + ":"
                            + tp.getCurrentMinute();
}});

alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
            alert.setTitle("Reminder");
            alert.setView(DTPicker);
            alert.show();
```

Comment: @kartik What is alert here, and what i have to use for context

Comment: context - your_ActivityName.this and  AlertDialog alert= new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();

Comment: hey there is some problem with your this line 
`ScrollView DTPicker = (ScrollView) View.inflate(context,
                    R.layout.date_time_picker, null);`

Comment: i tried to replace date_time_picker with my xml and context with my current activity but as my application comes in this phase it get forcefully stopped.

Comment: check the log cat message.What is the exception

Comment: 04-27 11:48:24.830: W/dalvikvm(812): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
04-27 11:48:24.851: E/AndroidRuntime(812): FATAL EXCEPTION: main